# Upgrading OpenCV brew formula: Python not loading properly

Tags: python, opencv, homebrew

I'm trying update the latest [opencv formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/opencv.rb) (as of writing, this formula installs opencv 2.4.7) to build the latest version of opencv (2.4.8).

The first thing I did was `brew edit opencv`, and change the url to 'https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/2.4.8.tar.gz' and update the checksum. I anticipated that I might have to deal with some built issues, but the problem I see seems to occur while the formula is being run.

Specifically, when I run `brew upgrade opencv` (or unlink and run `brew install opencv`), I get the following message:

```
==> Downloading https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/2.4.8.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/opencv-2.4.8.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file cmake/OpenCVFindOpenNI.cmake
Warning: Formula#python is deprecated and will go away shortly.
Error: undefined method `incdir' for #<PythonDependency: "python" []>
Please report this bug:   
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Formula/opencv.rb:49:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:165:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:272:in `brew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:617:in `stage'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:63:in `unpack'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/fileutils.rb:21:in `mktemp'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:60:in `unpack'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb:53:in `stage'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:615:in `stage'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:267:in `brew'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:144:in `install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:45:in `main'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/build.rb:12
/usr/local/Library/Formula/opencv.rb:80
```

Python doesn't seem to get loaded. I'm also confused by the deprecation warning; everything I've found suggests that python formula is the one I should be using. Judging by this [link](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python) the `depends_on :python` dependency seems like it should work (and it obviously did when I tried with the previous 2.4.7.1 formula).

For reference, here are my environment variables:

```
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-Ygtqzn/Render
CMD_DURATION=20.7s
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-a4CGwS/org.x:0
GEM_HOME=/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
GEM_PATH=/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
GREP_COLOR=97;45
GREP_OPTIONS=--color=auto
HOME=/Users/myname
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LOGNAME=myname
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig
PWD=/Users/myname/projects/forks/ruby-opencv
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/fish
SHLVL=1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-lvn79S/Listeners
TERM=xterm-color
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=273.1
TMPDIR=/var/folders/pv/pvvR8qgvGOCfd5dza+ZbVU+++TI/-Tmp-/
USER=myname
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
__fish_bin_dir=/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.0.0/bin
__fish_datadir=/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.0.0/share/fish
__fish_help_dir=/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.0.0/share/doc/fish
__fish_sysconfdir=/usr/local/Cellar/fish/2.0.0/etc/fish
rvm_bin_path=/Users/myname/.rvm/bin
rvm_path=/Users/myname/.rvm
rvm_prefix=/Users/myname
rvm_version=1.25.3:master
```

And python (homebrewed) version
`python --version #=>Python 2.7.6`

`brew doctor` output gives me a warning about a passenger config file (which shouldn't influence the building of opencv) and a warning that opencv is unlinked (I unlinked it to try running `brew install opencv`)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this issue by rolling back to an earlier homebrew version, then installing opencv, and then going back to the current version.

See this gist for detailed instructions: https://gist.github.com/frederikhermans/8561382

Comment: This installed for me but now get error: 
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for.
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Comment: My default python was 32bit while opencv was 64 bit.  Installed python from brew and replaced as default. Also had same issue as here: http://d.hatena.ne.jp/seinzumtode/20130421/1366513083  Waiting from fallout from changing python architecture but I can now do "import cv" Hurragh

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. I don't understand why "incdir" or other variables are not defined correctly in the formula file. But I solved this error by editing the opencv formula file as follows, (setting each path directly)

(around 50th lines)

> DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
>
> DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
>
> DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python

Comment: Worked for me, if you use the standard Apple Python version the paths are as follows (OS X 10.9.1):

DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR='/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/'
     DPYTHON_LIBRARY='/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib'

DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE='/usr/bin/python'